# How to get first row of a selected table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get first row of a selected table and specific column value:

```
   $ttleft = '';
    $st = $db->query("select * from recipes order by inde asc");
    while($row = $st->fetch()){
        $ttleft .= "<div class='ttleft'>" . $row['title'] . "</div>\n";
        // result: 323 525 727 - that's ok
        $ttop = $row['title'];
        // result: 727 - I need 323
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more clear.

Comment: @urfusion, code example is clear perfectly

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` to the query so only one row is returned?  Don't use a loop if you only want one record?

Comment: order by desc in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `$ttleft` in ASC order and `$ttop` equal to the smallest

```
$ttleft = '';
$st = $db->query("select * from recipes order by inde asc");
while($row = $st->fetch()){
    $ttleft .= "<div class='ttleft'>" . $row['title'] . "</div>\n";
    // result: 323 525 727 - that's ok
    if(!isset($ttop)){ 
        $ttop = $row['title']; 
        //result: 323
    }
}
```

else if you do not care about the order of `$ttleft` just order by desc

```
$st = $db->query("select * from recipes order by inde desc");
```

Comment: Nothing my friend =)